# How to check if my EC2 has access to s3 bucket in same account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I have an ec2 instance working on ubuntu 18.4.
and an s3 for in a same region.

I want my ec2 to connect to s3. My S3 is in a default state I just created it and have uploaded a file int it. Currently, the access state is "Bucket and objects not public".

I created a role which holds a policy

```
"Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
```

have attached the role to Ec2 instance.

I want to check if my ec2 will be able to access the S3 and how would I do that?

and

My ec2 is a web server which will access buckets for images, do I have to do anything else along with these steps?

Comment: Any application that uses an [AWS SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/) will automatically use the IAM Role when making API calls to AWS. However, I recommend that you limit the permissions granted in the policy. Granting `Action: *` means that any app or user on the instance can do _anything_ to that bucket, including deleting all content and even deleting the bucket. You might want to limit access to specific commands that are required, such as `GetObject` and `PutObject`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Typically you could **ssh into the instance**, install `awscli` on Ubuntu and run [aws s3 ls](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/ls.html) or similar command against the bucket you want.

For example:

```
sudo apt install -y awscli

aws s3 ls s3://bucketname
```

> My ec2 is a web server which will access buckets for images, do I have to do anything else along with these steps?

If your application uses AWS SDK, then you don't have to do anything. The **SDK will get credentials from your instance role**.

Also a **good practice** is to use [Grant Least Privilege](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html#grant-least-privilege) rule. Thus depending on your needs you could limit your policy to only read operations or just the actions you need, instead of using '*' for everything.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

As long as your S3 bucket does not have a bucket policy (which should not be there as you created in default state).

You should set your policy to the following to limit scope to S3

```
{
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*"
            ]
}
```

If you have the [AWS CLI installed](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-install.html) on your server you should be able to run a s3 CLI command such as `aws s3 ls s3://bucketname`. This should list all objects in the S3 bucket (including the file you created).

Comment: while running the command got this error :
An error occurred (IllegalLocationConstraintException) when calling the ListObjects operation: The me-south-1 location constraint is incompatible for the region specific endpoint this request was sent to.

Comment: Right can you try again with adding the region the S3 bucket is in via the `--region $REGION`?

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

In some cases sudo apt install -y awscli can throw space issues.
Please check Validate access to S3 buckets. on aws official page https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-instance-access-s3-bucket/